# Ajuda com LinQ Method usando group by Dinâmico

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, group-by

Preciso montar um gráfico dinâmico a partir de um painel de filtros e dois campos *select* que podem ser cruzados. Já tenho a estrutura que vai para o gráfico e como preciso retornar do *backend*.

No caso do *backend* tenho o código abaixo que retorna exatamente o que preciso, porém, preciso na verdade retornar dinamicamente.

```
List<RetornoConsulta> result = context.Atendimentos.Where(x => x.dt_atendimento >= dt_inicio)
                            .Where(x => x.dt_atendimento <= dt_fim)
                            .Select(g => new {
                                categories = g.Pessoa.publico_prioritario.ToString(),
                                name = g.Pessoa.tp_nacionalidade
                            })
                            .GroupBy(g => new {
                                categories = g.categories,
                                name = g.name
                            })
                            .Select(g => new RetornoConsulta
                             {
                                 data = g.Count(),
                                 categories = g.Key.categories.ToString(),
                                 name = g.Key.name
                             }).ToList();
                    ViewBag.result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Como falado, tenho que mandar duas *campos do banco* para serem cruzados, recebo eles no controller como *info1* e *info2*. Então no local que passo a instrução do *.Select* ao invés de ser passado do jeito que está acima, as variáveis info1 e info2 deveriam funcionar como o atributo da classe como a seguir:

```
.Select(g => new {
     categories = g.Pessoa.**[info1]**.ToString(),
     name = g.Pessoa.**[info2]**
 })
```

Eu havia tentado fazer isso usando o IQueryAble como mostrado abaixo, mas não consegui:

```
    public List<Atendimento> getGraficoAtendimentos(DateTime dt_inicio, DateTime dt_fim, string nm_sas = "", 
                string nm_distrito = "", string tipologia = "", string servico = "", string info1 = "", string info2 = "")
            {
                var atendimentos = _context.Atendimentos.AsQueryable();

                atendimentos = atendimentos.Where(x => x.dt_atendimento >= dt_inicio);
                atendimentos = atendimentos.Where(x => x.dt_atendimento <= dt_fim);
                if (nm_sas != "") atendimentos = atendimentos.Where(x => DbFunctions.Like(x.Pessoa.Domicilio.nm_prefeitura_regional, "%" + nm_sas + "%"));
                if (nm_distrito != "") atendimentos = atendimentos.Where(x => DbFunctions.Like(x.Pessoa.Domicilio.nm_distrito, "%" + nm_distrito + "%"));
                if (tipologia != "") atendimentos = atendimentos.Where(x => x.Servico.Tipologia.id.ToString() == tipologia);
                if (servico != "") atendimentos = atendimentos.Where(x => x.Servico.id.ToString() == servico);

                switch (info1)
                {
                    case "tp_raca": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_raca).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "genero": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.genero).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    //case "faixa_etaria": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_raca).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                    //    break;
                    case "tp_nacionalidade": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_nacionalidade).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "publico_prioritario": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.publico_prioritario).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "tp_estado_civil": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_estado_civil).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "tp_grau_dependencia": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_grau_dependencia).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "in_deficiencia": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.in_deficiencia).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "in_filhos": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.in_filhos).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    default: break;
            }

            switch (info2)
            {
                    case "tp_raca": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_raca).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "genero": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.genero).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    //case "faixa_etaria": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_raca).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                    //    break;
                    case "tp_nacionalidade": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_nacionalidade).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "publico_prioritario": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.publico_prioritario).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "tp_estado_civil": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_estado_civil).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "tp_grau_dependencia": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.tp_grau_dependencia).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "in_deficiencia": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.in_deficiencia).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    case "in_filhos": atendimentos = atendimentos.GroupBy(x => x.Pessoa.in_filhos).SelectMany(gr => gr);
                        break;
                    default: break;
            }
            return atendimentos.ToList();
        }
```

Então, como eu poderia fazer isso dinâmico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentei de diversas maneiras, mas só consegui resolver utilizando *if ternário*, pois a condição que preciso é acessar as propriedades durante o *group by* de um *select*, em que consistiu realizar em nível de objeto, ao qual apresentava erros ao tentar utilizar funções do controller, como se não existissem por estarem fora do escopo. A solução não ficou da melhor forma, digamos que é ruim para manutenção, mas foi o que consegui fazer funcionar.

Segue abaixo como ficou:

```
List<RetornoConsulta> result = atendimentos.Where(x => x.dt_atendimento >= dt_inicio)
                    .Where(x => x.dt_atendimento <= dt_fim)
                    .Select(g => new {
                        categories = (info1 == "tp_raca" ? g.Pessoa.tp_raca.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "genero" ? g.Pessoa.genero.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "tp_nacionalidade" ? g.Pessoa.tp_nacionalidade.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "publico_prioritario" ? g.Pessoa.publico_prioritario.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "tp_estado_civil" ? g.Pessoa.tp_estado_civil.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "tp_grau_dependencia" ? g.Pessoa.tp_grau_dependencia.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "in_deficiencia" ? g.Pessoa.in_deficiencia.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "in_filhos" ? g.Pessoa.in_filhos.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "in_servico_acolhimento" ? g.Pessoa.in_servico_acolhimento.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "in_situacao_escolar" ? g.Pessoa.in_situacao_escolar.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "tp_modalidade_ensino" ? g.Pessoa.tp_modalidade_ensino.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "tp_rede_ensino" ? g.Pessoa.tp_rede_ensino.ToString() :
                                    (info1 == "tp_grau_escolaridade" ? g.Pessoa.tp_grau_escolaridade.ToString() : ""))))))))))))),
                        name = (info2 == "tp_raca" ? g.Pessoa.tp_raca.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "genero" ? g.Pessoa.genero.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "tp_nacionalidade" ? g.Pessoa.tp_nacionalidade.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "publico_prioritario" ? g.Pessoa.publico_prioritario.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "tp_estado_civil" ? g.Pessoa.tp_estado_civil.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "tp_grau_dependencia" ? g.Pessoa.tp_grau_dependencia.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "in_deficiencia" ? g.Pessoa.in_deficiencia.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "in_filhos" ? g.Pessoa.in_filhos.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "in_servico_acolhimento" ? g.Pessoa.in_servico_acolhimento.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "in_situacao_escolar" ? g.Pessoa.in_situacao_escolar.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "tp_modalidade_ensino" ? g.Pessoa.tp_modalidade_ensino.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "tp_rede_ensino" ? g.Pessoa.tp_rede_ensino.ToString() :
                                (info2 == "tp_grau_escolaridade" ? g.Pessoa.tp_grau_escolaridade.ToString() : ""))))))))))))),
                    })
                    .GroupBy(g => new {
                        categories = g.categories,
                        name = g.name
                    })
                    .Select(g => new RetornoConsulta
                    {
                        data = g.Count(),
                        categories = g.Key.categories.ToString(),
                        name = g.Key.name.ToString()
                    }).ToList();
```